# How to validate RIA Services URL

Tags: c#, .net, validation, wcf-ria-services

I have this RIA Service URL:

```
 http://192.168.2.100/MegaSystem/Services/RIAServicesLibraryMain-Web-Version_1_0-DomainService.svc
```

So I need to validate this URL somehow in the configuration window of the my application.

I use this method to do it:

```
private bool KickServices(string serviceUrl)
        {
            bool result = false;

            var request = WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request != null)
            {
                request.ContentType = "application/xml";
                request.Method = "GET";
            }

            if (request != null)
            {
                var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    result = true;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

The main problem if I use some incorrect URL like

```
http://192.168.2.100/MegaSystem/Services/RIAServicesLibraryMain-Web-Version_1_0-DomainService_SHIT_SHIT_SHIT.svc
```

It returns TRUE anyway...

Please help me to find correct way to validate RIA Services URL.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found good solution:

```
private bool KickServices(string serviceUrl)
        {
            bool result = false;

            var request = WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request != null)
            {
                request.ContentType = "application/xml";
                request.Method = "GET";
            }

            if (request != null)
            {
                var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    string resultContent = null;
                    Encoding responseEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), responseEncoding))
                    {
                        resultContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        if (resultContent.Contains(serviceUrl))
                            result = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```